# Does anyone know the Campaign Badges for the Second Purging of Lastrati or the 3rd War for Armageddon?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I am in the process of painting an obscure Space Marine army of mine called the *Storm Giants*. Due to having a similar name to the *Storm Lords*, I was looking to include a campaign badge from either of the aforementioned campaigns. However, I am having trouble finding images online of badges from either campaign. **Does anyone know where I can find these badges, or know what they look like?**

Comment: Having trouble figuring what's a 'campaign badge' - where is it painted on the miniature?

Comment: Also, a quick Google shows these two chapters have a different color scheme: **Storm Giants** are gold/yellow, with a red lightning insignia on left shoulder (and other selected spots such as their back, helmet etc.), and tactical designation painted red and white on right shoulder. **Storm Lords** have gold/yellow helmets, armors half red (right) half white (left), with a skull and three lightning insignia on left shoulder and white tactical designation on right. Seems to me it'll be quite difficult to confuse one for the other...

Comment: @G0BLiN - campaign badges are conflict specific identifiers, generally painted on the shoulder pad/greave/knee of space marines, and anywhere on vehicles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Campaign Badges are often conflict, and chapter, specific, and finding any definitive one is proving quite difficult.

From what I can remember of playing the actual 3rd War for Armageddon campaign (showing my age now!), there wasn't an overall Campaign Badge for Imperial Forces, but there were a number of area/region specific badges that were used.

Generally, they are reasonably simple geometric design (i.e. quartered diamonds, triangles etc).

I did find this image showing a Salamanders Librarian with an Armageddon Campaign marking, but whether it's 2nd or 3rd War I don't know, and I know that there's been a bit of discussion about it on Warseer/Dakka.

[image]

I will see if I can dig up some more though